# Move points in plane to a line via non-overlapping paths

Tags: geometry, algorithms, plane-geometry, computational-geometry

If we have $k$ points in an infinite 2-dimensional real plane, is there an algorithm to "move" those points to some line $L$ in the plane via completely non-overlapping paths? The $k$ points are arbitrarily placed but in unique positions.

Alternatively, the problem can be phrased as connecting each point $p_i$ to a line $L$ via a line segment such that none of the line segments overlap.

Comment: Since there are finitely many points, their image under orthogonal projection to the line will be discrete. If two points have the same orthogonal projection, then the lines can be perturbed by a small amount so that they don't overlap.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Taking @David Sheard's comment and running with it:

Suppose two or more points have the same orthogonal projection onto $L$. Then we can separate these projections $-$ fan them out, if you will $-$ by rotating all the lines by the same angle $\theta$:

- if points $P$ and $Q$ are on opposite sides of $L$, their projections will get shifted in opposite directions;
- if they are on the same side of $L$, then their distances $\ell_P,\ell_Q$ to $L$ must be different, so their projections will get shifted by different amounts $\ell_P\tan\theta$ and $\ell_Q\tan\theta$. The shifted lines won't meet, becaue they are all parallel to each other.

And because the number of points is finite, we can make $\theta$ small enough that no rotated line meets the shifted projection of any other points.